# slow whoosh searches

Tags: python, indexing, whoosh

I am getting close to 1000 search results in 15 seconds after having created a whoosh index with a simple schema and indexed 1.5 million records.

```
schema = Schema(tax_id=STORED, name=TEXT(stored=True))
```

The size of MAIN*.seg file is about 190 Mb.

The way I am searching is as follows

```
 ix=open_dir("index")
  with ix.searcher() as searcher:
        query = QueryParser("name", ix.schema).parse(u'putrefaciens')
         results = searcher.search(query)
```

I am wondering if this performance is on the expected lines of can we do faster full text searching with whoosh given the index size.

Comment: Since Whoosh changes everytime (for the better), which version are/were you using ? Even though you have many documents in your index, this is unacceptable performance, even for Whoosh. This should not take more than 3 (arbitrary) seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is helpful in your application, but I just wanted to note that TEXT fields are doing more complex stuff than ID fields.

In my application of whoosh, I have a "name" TEXT field, which I use for "processed" indexing/searching. So one can just enter some word and it'll be found if it is in the name.

I also have a "name_exact" ID field, if I just want to do "as is" and precise indexing/lookup.

If the latter is enough for your application, you could just try performance with an ID field.

As Steve K already noted, using a recent whoosh (or even repo tip) might help also.